# Page does not reload when changing query params through 'next/router' Router.push()

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using nextjs for my application. On updating query parameters of a page, the page should get re-rendered. For some reason that is not happning. Some online article suggests that we should get the new query props in componentWillReceiveProps, but that too isn't happening. Need help.

/*----- modules/my-component.js ------*/

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import Router from 'next/router'


class MyComponent extends Component {
  someEvent = () => {
    Router.push({
      pathname: '/logs',
      query: { keyword: 'blah' }
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div onClick={this.someEvent}>Click Me</div>
    )
  }
}
export default MyComponent
```

/*----- pages/logs.js ------*/

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'
import MyComponent from '~/modules/my-component'
import Router from 'next/router'


class Logs extends Component {
  componentWillUpdate(props){
    //does not get printed
    console.log("================componentWillUpdate", this.props.router.query)
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    //does not get printed
    console.log("================componentWillReceiveProps", this.props.router.query)
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div>My Logs page</div>
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(Logs)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I see something strange with your `someEvent = keyword => {` function. Is that the actual code, or an example you created for SO?

Because if you call it like this: `<div onClick={this.someEvent}>Click Me</div>`, then `keyword` will actually be an event, not a keyword.

It also seems like you aren't referencing `props` anywhere in your JSX for the `Logs` component. You should try to reference it.

Third, what is the call to `withRouter(Logs)`? That isn't standard. By default in Next.js you should have the component exported by default.

Are you using a custom router? If so, then it's likely not going to work with functions in `'next/router'`. Next.js which comes with its own router.

Try to export the component by default and to make sure that `keyword` is an actual keyword, not an event.

Comment: 1- someEvent is just a sample code I wrote here. Be assured that proper method and parameter passing is happening in my actual code. 

2- withRouter is just an HOC provided in next/router package, to make router query params available to the component in its props

3- Not using any custom routing. Using Router from 'next/router'